# TBS TV card drivers not compliling with latest kernel

Tags: 18.04, drivers

I have the following TBS TV cards installed TBS6281se - dual terestrial and TBS6902 - dual satalite but since upgrading the kernel to 4.15.0-118 this morning their drivers will not compile.
This what I always do after a kernel upgrade:
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/
cd media_build
sudo ./install.sh
cd
These are the drivers I'm using tbs-linux-drivers_v170330 and it has been working for many years.
I have also tried the latest drivers - tbs-open-linux-drivers_v20200707 to no avail.
I have reverted to kernel 4.15.0-117 and all is well.
What will happen when I upgrade to ubuntu 20.04?
Thanks in advance for your help,
Regards, Brian.

Answer (score 0):

*on my main machine I installed ubuntu 20.04, then

git clone https://github.com/tbsdtv/media_build.git

ls
cd media_build/
ls
./build il

*build told me to do this

sudo make install

*so I did and they installed
*the rest of the tbsdtv solution, which I haven't done

sudo install lsdiff
sudo apt install lsdiff
sudo apt install patchutils libproc-processtable-perl
./build
sudo make install
sudo make rmmod

*I did this and it loaded

sudo modprobe saa716x_tbs-dvb

lsmod|grep saa
saa716x_tbs_dvb        65536  0
cx24117                36864  1 saa716x_tbs_dvb
saa716x_core           81920  1 saa716x_tbs_dvb
tas2101                28672  1 saa716x_tbs_dvb
dvb_core              151552  2 saa716x_tbs_dvb,saa716x_core
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 saa716x_tbs_dvb,radeon

*I now have to install ubuntu 20.04 on my media player machine and keep my fingers crossed.

I have upgraded my media player machine to ubuntu 20.04 and I can confirm that the above solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behaviour since a few days. It seems that the script builds the modules for a previous kernel, not the current. I found 2 solutions that actually work:

1. remove all kernels except the current, build again.
   or
2. delete media and media_build directory, pull from github again, build.